# ListBox VBA Userform

Tags: vba, listbox, userform

Hi am trying to make a booking form for a dog agility field with a date and time slots have near enough done it the only issue i have is double booking so i would like to within the book cmd button to check the monthview1 in the data sheet and to check if the time is available on the chosen date.

any help would be massively appreciated, hope this make sense below is the code i have which the booking form work fine with.

Comment: Please post code showing what you achieved so far and eventual error messages. So that one can point what problem is happening and be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

in a ideal world i would like the listbox to show available rooms on the dates selected. but this is what i have atm. this is with in the listboxclick vba code

`If MonthView1 = Sheets("Camping Bookings")("G:G") Then esleif MonthView2 = Sheets("Camping Bookings")("H:H") Then esleif ListBox1 = Sheets("Camping Bookings")("F:F")then MsgBox "booking is not available" exit sub end if`

Comment: Please edit the original post as this is no answer but an addition to the question. Allow me a remark: SO expects a new question not only to include the desired behaviour, but that you describe the **core problem** or error you are confronted with by showing typically the *shortest* (i.e. `M`inimal) code (*even pseudo code*) with *all* necessary parts (i.e. `C`omplete) to reproduce the issue in a *verifiable* way (i.e. `V`erifiable).   - See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).